# How to truncate a control based on window width?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to resize a controls' width and content based on the size of its parent window. For example:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>  
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Width="100" Background="Red" />
            <Border Width="100" Background="Green" />
            <Border Width="100" Background="Blue" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When the window is resized to be smaller then 300 pixel wide I want to Borders to have a with of e.g. 30. How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create columns in your `Grid` and set `MaxWidth` to 100:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" />
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" />
</Grid>
```

or if you want to limit `Width` of the whole `Grid` then this should work:

```
<Grid MaxWidth="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" />
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" />
</Grid>
```

in this case available space (up to 300) will be divided equally between all columns.

**EDIT**

Another solution for more complicated rules can be custom `IValueConverter`:

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var width = (double)value;
        if (width > 300)
            return 100;
        else
            return 30;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>        
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" />
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to change the controls' width dynamically. I really want to change the width "in steps".

Comment: can you define _in steps_?

Comment: Yes - as I wrote I want the width of the Borders to be 100, when the windows width is less then 300 I want the Borders to be 30 width. Another example: open Word and change the window size. The Toolbar changes its contents depending on windows width (some items are "compacted"). This is the effect I want to simulate.

Comment: @user1130329, check my edit. If I understand well you can achieve that with `IValueConverter`